# xml attribute not working in xml, only in code

Tags: android, xml

I use a layout with an ImageButton in it.
When I set the attribute

```
android:focusable="false"
```

in the xml file the button can still get the focus.

When I do this in the code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.planning_line);
    View knop = findViewById(R.id.button_calendar);
    knop.setFocusable(false);
```

it works.

What is the difference between setting an attribute in the xml-file and in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is as it should be, because the 'focusable' attribute is explicitly set to the value 'true' in the ImageButton constructor code:

```
    public ImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

What remains is the question why this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`